# Facebook app review getting auto rejected for manages_pages feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I had earlier been provided permission for the feature Manage_pages. However, Facebook has changed it policies and this feature has been depreciated, moreover, my application wasn't using much of the Facebook feature. For these 2 reasons, my app has been disabled.

SO, i submitted a review for the same. The feedback is as such:
[image: App review 1]
[image: App review 2]

The main purpose of my app is to take payments through the client's Facebook page , for which earlier used Manage_pages feature. Now, even if i hit the connect button, it says "The app is in dev mode" . Am stuck here, how can i get the button to work and display a screen cast if I keep getting the same error. this seems like an endless while loop :(

Now, when i am trying to re-submit an app review, it seems to be getting auto rejected.
Any insight would be appreciated!

Here is my Facebook controller code

```
class FacebookController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  skip_before_action :authorize

  def connect
    # get array of facebook pages added
    page_ids = params[:tabs_added].keys
    # create or update connection for each facebook page added
    page_ids.each do |page_id|
      page = FacebookPage.where(page_id: page_id).first_or_initialize
      page.update!(slug_id: params[:slug_id], form_type: params[:form_type])
    end

    head :created
  end

  def show
    request = parse_signed_request(params[:signed_request]).try(:[], 'page')
    facebook_page = FacebookPage.find_by(page_id: request.try(:[], 'id'))
    facebook_admin = request.try(:[], 'admin')
    if facebook_page
      redirect_to contribution_form_url(
        subdomain: facebook_page.account_type,
        id: facebook_page.slug.name,
        form_type: facebook_page.form_type,
        iframe: true,
        facebook: true,
        facebook_admin: facebook_admin,
        facebook_page: facebook_page
      )
    else
      render nothing: true
    end
  end

  def update
    facebook_page = FacebookPage.find(params[:id])
    slug = Slug.find_by!(name: page_params[:form_slug], account_type: facebook_page.account_type)
    if facebook_page.update!(slug: slug, form_type: page_params[:form_type])
      redirect_to contribution_form_url(
        subdomain: facebook_page.account_type,
        id: facebook_page.slug.name,
        form_type: facebook_page.form_type,
        iframe: true,
        facebook: true,
        facebook_admin: true,
        facebook_page: facebook_page
      )
    end
  end

  private
    def parse_signed_request(signed_request)
      # We only care about the data after the '.'
      payload = signed_request.split('.')[1]
      # Facebook gives us a base64URL encoded string.
      # Ruby only supports base64 out of the box, so we have to add padding to make it work
      payload += '=' * (4 - payload.length.modulo(4))

      decoded_json = Base64.decode64(payload)
      JSON.parse(decoded_json)
    end

    def page_params
      params.require(:facebook_page).permit(:form_type, :form_slug)
    end
end
```

and i am also attaching the the script which opens the facebook tab

```
<script>

  function move_to_top( value )
  {
    $(".fb_dialog").each(function(index) {
        if($(this).css("top")!='-10000px') {
            $(this).css("top", value + 'px' );
        }
    });
    setTimeout( ('move_to_top("'+value+'");'), 1250);
  }  

  window.addToFacebook = function() {
    // make sure logged in as user; not page
    FB.login(function(loginResponse) {
      // if they are correctly logged in as user
      if (loginResponse.authResponse) {
        // popup modal to add form to page
        FB.ui({
          method: 'pagetab',
          display: 'popup'
        }, function(response) {
          // if tabs were added, make the connection
          if (Object.keys(response.tabs_added).length > 0) {
            console.log("inside")
            response.form_type = $('[name=form_type]:checked').val().slice(0,1);
            response.slug_id = '<%= Slug.find_by(name: slug, account_type: candidate.account_type).try(:id) || candidate.account_slug.id %>';
            $.post('/facebook/connect', response);

            $.magnificPopup.open({
              items: {
                src: '<%=j render "form_settings/facebook_success" %>',
                type: 'inline'
              }
            });

          }
        });
        $(".fbProfileBrowserResult").ready( function(){
          t = setTimeout ( ('move_to_top("'+50+'")'), 1250 );
        });
      }
    });
  };
</script>

<p><%= link_to 'Connect with Facebook', '#', onclick: 'addToFacebook()', class: 'button' %></p>
```

Comment: _'Now, even if i hit the connect button, it says "The app is in dev mode"'_ - are you doing this while logged into Facebook as a user that has a role in the app? You should be able to test with those.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error even with Test User. I suppose , the only option here is to submit a review